# change numericInput value based on current value when user changes another input

Tags: r, shiny

I'm creating a shiny app that is based in inches, but would like to allow the user to change the units to centimeters. When the user changes the units (in either direction), I would like the current value of a numericInput to change appropriately. Here is what I have come up with:

```
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    numericInput("length","Length",1),
    radioButtons("units", "Units", c(Inches="inches", Centimeters="cms"))
  ),
  server = function(input,output,session) {
    observe({
      updateNumericInput(session, inputId="length", value=ifelse(input$units=="cms", input$length*2.54,input$length/2.54))
    })
  }
)
```

As you will see if you run the app, currently the problem with my code is that there is an infinite loop because when `input$length` gets changed, the `observe` gets called again and `input$length` gets updated, and the pattern repeats.

At default, `input$length=1` and `input$units="inches"`. What I would like to occur is that if the user changes to `input$units="cms"`, then `input$length` changes to `2.54`. If the user subsequently changes back to inches, then `input$length` changes back to `1`. At this point, if the user changes the `input$length` to `2` and then changes `input$units` to `"cms"`, then `input$length` should be updated to `5.08`. How can I get this to work as desired?

An idea that I'm not sure how to program is to only have the `observe` run when `input$units` changes rather than when either `input$units` or `input$length` changes, but I'm certainly open to any solution.

Comment: Try enclosing `input$length` into `isolate`: `updateNumericInput(session, inputId="length", value=ifelse(input$units=="cms", isolate(input$length)*2.54,isolate(input$length)/2.54))`

Comment: I didn't know about `isolate`, but it works perfectly. Make it an answer and I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a job for `isolate`: when you don't want that a change in an input triggers an event, you can `isolate` the expression containing the input. Try:

```
updateNumericInput(session, inputId="length", value=ifelse(input$units=="cms", isolate(input$length)*2.54,isolate(input$length)/2.54))
```